# PDF Error 144: Invalid TrueType data found

Tags: node.js, pdf, printing

I'm trying to print a PDF using *ipp npm module* but I get this error printed on the paper:

```
PDF Error 144: Invalid TrueType data found
Assert Failed: cmap_off > -1
```

The Buffer created does not have any issues, if I save it in a file and print it, it works, but not if I send it through *ipp*.

Does anyone have an idea of what this error could mean?

Answer (score 0):

The issue was happening because of wrong formatting with the PDF itself.